# Sprite Kit PhysicsBody, check if two bodies touch each other

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite

Is there somehow in Sprite Kit I can detect if two physicsBody touch each other? any delegates?. I'm not interested in didBeginContact or didEndContact as I need something between these two :)

Now I have this code so far

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    self.contactWithEnemy = YES;
}

- (void)didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    self.contactWithEnemy = NO;

}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    if(self.contactWithEnemy == YES) {
      if([_tusk actionForKey:@"punch"]) {
        NSLog(@"HIT");
    }
}
```

}

But from here, how would I be able to deal with the target I "hit" ? :)

Comment: Please don't create two duplicate questions.

Comment: My mistake Fogmeister :/

Comment: No worries :D Just keeping things clear around here :D I actually went in to answer this before I recognised your account avatar :D

Comment: In fact, this is not a duplicate of his other question.

Comment: @s.bandara it was before the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You mention `didBeginContact` and `didEndContact` as existing delegate methods. You can use those two methods to set and unset a flag that indicates touching, and you can query its state whenever you need to.

Comment: Perfectly makes sense now. Haven't thought of that :s . Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

[iOS Sprite Kit Collision with movement through elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019951/ios-sprite-kit-collision-with-movement-through-elements)

I answered it here for you about an hour ago :)